# Adding image icons in tab bar (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, tabbar, android-assets

I'm new to Flutter. I want to create a tab bar with image icons like in the image below.

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please provide a code snippet?

Comment: To get the view, I used a Container widget and a Listview as a child of the Container widget. But I know that is not the proper approach to add image icons to a tab bar.           Container(
                height: 60.0,
                width: 370.0,
                child: ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                    
                        Container()

Comment: Container(
                          height: 45.0,
                          width: 50.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                          child: ClipOval(
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/logo1.jpg',
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),